# How do I properly integrate KuKoin API w/ secret, passphrase, and key signature using Google Apps Script?

Tags: java, google-apps-script, key, signature, secret-key

Over the past few days I've been trying to engineer a piece of code that can help me access this api https://api-futures.kucoin.com and this endpoint /api/v1/transaction-history?offset=1&forward=true&maxCount=50 using hash encryption.

Reference document https://docs.kucoin.com/futures/#authentication . I've been looking at the reference document, then I have written a script that should work but is not and I just need some guidance.

```js
function KuCoinRequest(){
    // GET /api/v1/transaction-history?offset=1&forward=true&maxCount=50
    var key ='xx'
    var secret = 'xx'
    var passphrase = 'xx' 
    var url = "https://api-futures.kucoin.com"; //endpoint
    var timestamp = '' + Number(new Date().getTime()).toFixed(0);
    var command = "GET";
    var endpoint = "/api/v1/transaction-history?offset=1&forward=true&maxCount=50"
    var str_to_sign = timestamp + command + endpoint;
    // var signature = Utilities.computeHmacSha256(str_to_sign, secret);
    // var encodedPass = Utilities.computeHmacSha256(passphrase, secret);
    var signature = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_256, str_to_sign, secret)
    var encodedPass = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_256, passphrase, secret);
    var params = {
        'method': "GET",
        'headers' : {
            'KC-API-SIGN': Utilities.base64Encode(signature),
            'KC-API-KEY': key,
            'KC-API-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,         
            'KC-API-PASSPHRASE': Utilities.base64Encode(encodedPass),     
            'KC-API-KEY-VERSION': '2',     
            'muteHttpExceptions': true       
        }
    };         
    query = url + endpoint;      
    var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(query, params);
    Logger.log(data.getContentText());   
    // printJsonKucoin(data, endpoint); 
    return data;
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue from `have written a script that should work but is not`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? For example, if an error occurs, can you provide it?

Comment: @Tanaike so in the logger I get this - 10:58:07 PM Info {"code":"200000","data":{"dataList":[],"hasMore":false}}. but I want the data associated with this endpoint to show up on a spreadsheet, rather than the logger. Although. when I use return it's just blank in the cell. If you're familiar with API and signatures with keys and secrets, does my code look correct? thanks.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `"code":"200000"`, in this case, the document says `A successful response is indicated by an HTTP status code 200 and system code 200000.`. So I think that the request is correct. About `"data":{"dataList":[],"hasMore":false}`, in this case, when your endpoint and your token are used, are there the possibility of no values? I'm worried about it.

Comment: @Tanaike So my endpoint is -api/v1/transaction-history and since I've been trading recently, I can only assume that it would populate the trade history connected to my account api, passphrase, and secret. Do you think that the data isn't being called correctly? thanks.

Comment: how would I return results to sheet cells?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From the response code, it is considered that your request is correct. So, for example, in this case, how about asking your current issue to the administrator of API? About `how would I return results to sheet cells?`, I cannot know the actual response values. So I cannot propose the sample script. I apologize for this.